# Dúvida com generics em Java

Tags: java, genéricos

Tenho uma classe que usa tipo genéricos

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO <T extends Entidade>{
    //corpo da classe
}
```

Em certo momento eu preciso saber a classe de T, o compilador não aceita usar `T.class`.

```
public void remover(Long id) throws NonexistentEntityException {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            T entidade;
            try {
                //Nesse momento preciso saber a classe de T.
                entidade = em.getReference(T.class, id);
                entidade.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("A entidade com id "+id+" não existe", enfe);
            }
            em.remove(entidade);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Em que momento? Mostre que o precisa.

Comment: Olá. Marquei a resposta como duplicata porque a resposta do @AnthonyAccioly responde perfeitamente essa pergunta. Basta fazer `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]`para pegar o tipo.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo, funcionou.